# In a user service, it possible to inherit environment variables from the user session?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, systemd-user

Normally, services started with Systemd are given a "clean" environment that does not inherit from the user session. This is by design and it is a good default.

However, I've written some services for myself (e.g. `~/.config/systemd/user/foo.service`) where it would be convenient to inherit the environment variables I set up in my X session, such as `XDG_DATA_HOME`.

I do not want to have to hard code the values of environment variables into each service.

**Is there some way to indicate to systemd that I *do* want to inherit the environment in which user services are started?**

**Or at least (and maybe better) can I whitelist specific environment variables to be inherited?**

Currently my environment variables are configured in a POSIX shell script that I source in both `~/.xsessionrc` (and its non-Debian equivalents) for X and `~/.profile` for the shell.

If it helps, I am willing to move this config to `~/.pam_environment`, but this will require some fragile hacking. My OS-provided (Debian) configuration for my chosen display manager (LightDM) sets `user_readenv=0` in `pam_env.so`, so I would have to make a systemwide configuration change that I would then have to worry about keeping synchronized and correct after package updates.

Of course, I could submit a patch to the Debian package that changes this default, but it's probable that the default is the way it is for a good reason, and I doubt my own selfish use case would be enough to convince them to except such a patch.

Another option is to change from `ExecStart=foo -a -b` to `ExecStart=sh -c 'exec foo -a -b'`. This is somewhat distasteful, because I have had problems in the past with Systemd losing track of the `foo` process, thinking it had successfully exited when in fact it had crashed with a non-zero exit status. Maybe I "did it wrong" and could try it again. But this feels like even more of a kludge than using PAM env, and I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: An idea based on the docs. `systemctl` has an [`import-environment`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20import-environment%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VARIABLE%E2%80%A6%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20) command that can apparently pass environment variables from the client to the systemd manager. For user service managers, this environment is passed to the executed processes (as per https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PassEnvironment=). (1/2)

Comment: So setting up the variables, then running `system import-environment ...`, and then starting the user service should allow the user service to inherit the said variables. See the links for details. (2/2)

Comment: Thanks! I will read that and self-answer if I can.

Comment: `PassEnvironment=` specifically looks like what I had in mind.